# Unable to Synchronize the Database (Python 3.4 + Visual Studio Express 2013)

Tags: python, django

I have been struggling for days with trying to get django setup on my server. I can't install via pip because of firewall issues at work, and installed via setup.py after downloading the files.

however when I try to sync 'Django sync DB' via Visual Studio, I get the error, "unknown command: 'syncdb' "...image link: http://imageshack.com/a/img673/3726/AKpQn8.png

when I try to create new django project (django-admin startproject mysite) via PowerShell or cmd, it creates an empty folder missing the manage.py, settings.py, and other associated files

I have tried all options researched over the net including using either django-admin or django-admin.py, to updating the path in my environmental variables to point to /site-packages/django/bin

django 1.9, and python 3.4 is installed as it appears when checking version via cmd

I tried searching for the project files so I can download, and install manually without any luck

Please advise how to get this running, as been struggling for days now, and have exhausted all options advised

Looking forward to your favorable response

Regards,

Comment: Related: [What should I use instead of syncdb in Django 1.9?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29683494/what-should-i-use-instead-of-syncdb-in-django-1-9)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try an older version of Django. 1.9 is in development. Install 1.7.

Comment: and it looks like syncdb is removed from 1.9, so that would explain that.